Turning 48V phantom power to 9V
I've got a JTS CX-156W mic which require 9V phantom power supply, but I've got an audio interface which delivers a 48V phantom power.
Currently I have an external battery power supply (JTS PS-500) which delivers a 9V phantom power and I connect it to my interface with a jack so that phantom power however activated does not enter this part of the circuit.
Do I have a better option, where I don't uuse this external battery ?
Edit: Sorry it's actually CX-516W (not 156)

The PS510M seems to accept phantom power. https://www.jts-europe.com/products/microphones-and-wireless-systems/accessories/ps-510m/

Have you checked alternativs from JTS? It seems to me that a MA500 would be the correct solution. http://www.jts.com.tw/english/products/detail.php?fid=1&subid=8&pid=230

Could this be the JTS CX-516 (instead of CX-156)?  If so, the JTS web site page for the CX-516 says the phantom power spec is 9-52 Volts.  I.e., you can use your interface's phantom power.
Double check the make/model number first, though.
BTW, the same website lists the PS-500 battery power supply as having XLR input and output connectors, so it's not the usual single-ended power supply for a consumer-grade condenser mic, it's a battery version of a phantom supply.  A bit more evidence this mic can probably handle 48V phantom power.  (But still double check first!)

Edit:  The OP has said the microphone is the CX-516W wireless, which has a phantom power spec of 3-5V.  So the 48V phantom power from the interface is not compatible with the microphone.  Using the PS-500 battery pack (power supply) will be necessary.  The PS-500 manual suggests its output can be connected to your interface.  Ideally your interface would have its 48V phantom power disabled on that input channel, but it might work with 48V phantom power enabled.

(I edited, it is CX-516W.) OK, I didn't see that, thanks for your interest. So I just have to connect my mics to the XLR entries of my interface then. I should buy an adapter from mini-XLR (for my mics) to XLR (for my interface) also, I assume.

In fact, it is really 516W and not 516. According to the notice, this one requires 3 to 5 V Phantom Power...
